# Inconsistent Rating Bar Progress Tint color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RatingBar added to my layout:

```
    <RatingBar
       android:id="@+id/detailRating"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:numStars="5"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
       android:progressTint="#FFEB3B"/>
```

And as you can see i have set the progress tint to yellow (#FFEB3B). Now on my device (Nexus 5), the rating bar progress is in fact yellow and my problem is the progress color changes on other devices. How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post details on what android version you see the tint and what version you see erroneous tint?

Comment: On android 2.3 the progress tint is green on android 4.3 it's blue.

Comment: Ok, what I can guess is that  style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" might be having different implementation for different android versions. How about trying a custom implementation for the style. Check out this link - http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

Comment: Yeah, end the end i have created my own rating bar style. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end I have addressed my problem by creating my own progress drawable:

```
ratingstars_small.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@android:id/background"
       android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_rate_empty" />
   <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
       android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_rate_empty" />
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
       android:drawable="@mipmap/icon_rate_full" />
</layer-list>
```

and on my Rating bar xml:

```
<RatingBar
   android:id="@+id/rb"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:numStars="5"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="right"
   style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingstars_small"/>
```

Also for custom images these are the sizes:

For style `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

```
mdpi: 16px
hdpi: 24px
xhdpi: 32px
xxhdpi: 48px
```

and for style `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"`

```
mdpi: 35px
hdpi: 52px
xhdpi: 69px
xxhdpi: 105px
```

I hope those who have the same issues find this very useful.